# Contour integral of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos( \omega )}{\omega^2(a^2 + \omega^2)}d\omega$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

The title states the integral in question.

I have tried arguing that there is no pole in $z=0$ because $$(1-\cos(z))/z^2 \approx (1-1+z^2)/z^2 = 1.$$ Then using the contour of a half circle in the upper half plane and rewriting cosine in terms of complex exponentials and use the residue thm. to get: $-\pi (1-\exp(-at))/a^3$. But this does not seem to be the right answer.

If $z=0$ is a pole of order 2, then I should avoid it in my contour, but I do not know what the contribution to the integral is then.

If it was a simple pole it would contribute with half the residue, but what about a pole of order 2?

Comment: I don't see a connection between que question at the end of your post and the rest of the post. As you wrote, the function that you are trying to integrate has *no* pole at $0$:

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{1-\cos\omega}{\omega^2(a^2+\omega^2)}$ is indeed regular at $\omega=0$, but the plan to put $\cos\omega=(e^{i\omega}+e^{-i\omega})/2$ breaks when trying to let the radius of the half-circle tend to $\infty$, because $e^{-i\omega}$ "explodes". Instead, you can drive this way with integrand $\dfrac{1-e^{i\omega}}{\omega^2(a^2+\omega^2)}$ (which has a simple pole at $\omega=0$ so your last note applies).

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to work!